# how to split a row into csv depending of the content?

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, split, data-modeling

my fisrt question, please dont be hard

I' reading a csv file with a list of employees already ordered by "Department"
and  i have to split them by department and then create a 2nd .csv file with this report with an especific format, like below.

Example original file:

> ### departments, id, first_name, last_name,
>
> dept1          ,321,julio, javier,
>
> dept1          ,123,Maria, contreras,
>
> dept2          ,258,michael, something
>
> dept2          ,951,ruben, lake
>
> dept3          ,456,judith,soto
>
> dept3          ,753,jhon, jairo
>
> dept3          ,654,josue, castillo
>
> dept3          ,842,estephany, mendez

And im trying to do something like this:

> ### Dept1 :
>
> departments, id, first_name, last_name,
>
> dept1          ,321,julio, javier,
>
> dept1          ,123,Maria, contreras,
>
> ### Dept2 :
>
> departments, id, first_name, last_name,
>
> dept2          ,258,michael, something
>
> dept2          ,951,ruben, lake
>
> ### Dept3 :
>
> departments, id, first_name, last_name,
>
> dept3          ,456,judith,soto
>
> dept3          ,753,jhon, jairo
>
> dept3          ,654,josue, castillo
>
> dept3          ,842,estephany, mendez

Comment: Hello Koby, please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read e.g. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should first try something by yourself and include the problematic source code. Your question, as it is, give the impression that you want us to do the homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is use the "indexOf" method, and then take that and put it in a hashmap. Then output the hashmaps.